# python is not assigning

Tags: python, variable-assignment

This probably is a really dumb question but when I type an answer, It is the correct answer, but it still says  "incorrect, the answer is....." then prints out the answer I typed to begin with, so it isn't assigning 'rightanswer' to answer'. help?? (this is the newer version of python so the parenthesis are needed)

```
import random
ops = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
num1 = (random.randint(1,10))
num2 = (random.randint(1,10))
operation = (random.choice(ops))

maths = (num1, operation, num2)

print (maths)

answer = input("what is the answer to the above sum?")

if operation == "/":
    CorrectAnswer = (num1/num2)
elif operation == "*":
    CorrectAnswer = (num1*num2)
elif operation == "-":
    CorrectAnswer = (num1-num2)
else:
    CorrectAnswer = (num1+num2)

time.sleep(1)
if answer == CorrectAnswer:
    print ("correct!")
else:
    print ("incorrect, the answer is", CorrectAnswer)
```

Comment: Since this almost certainly about your [GCSE programming problem](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2gawvg/gcse_computing_programming_tasks_14_16_year_olds/), please do read [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166).

Comment: Side note: in your message to the user, "above sum" should only allow `+` operation problems, but obviously that's not the case.

Comment: To martijn Pieters - Don't mean to sound stuck up, yes I am a student but I am also 2 years before my GCSE's and there isn't a computing course available in my school so I decided to teach myself. Sorry if you think I wasted your time.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3, `input()` returns a *string*; strings are never equal to integers or floating point numbers:

```
>>> input('Enter the number 42: ') == 42
Enter the number 42: 42
False
>>> '42' == 42
False
```

Convert the answer to an integer or float first before testing it against your calculated `CorrectAnswer` integer:

```
answer = int(input("what is the answer to the above sum?"))
```

The [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) and [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) functions can do this conversion for you, but take into account that they'll raise a `ValueError` exception if the input is not convertible.

See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) if you want to handle incorrect input better, by catching that exception and re-prompting for an answer.

If you are going to use `float()`, take into account that floating point values are *approximations*, and a user typing in `0.33` while your `1 / 3` expression actually produces `0.3333333333333333` is likely to lead to issues:

```
>>> 1/3
0.3333333333333333
>>> float('0.33') == 1/3
False
```

See [What is the best way to compare floats for almost-equality in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python) for approaches to how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

`input` will return a string, but `CorrectAnswer` is a numeric type, such as `float`. You should convert `answer` to a float and then compare -

`if float(answer) == CorrectAnswer`